# Is LLVM an exception to the rule for avoiding dynamic casts?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, llvm, dynamic-cast

LLVM has it's own hand rolled alternative to RTTI that is a speed improvement over built-in RTTI and allows dynamic casting to classes with no vtable (`dyn_cast`). However, it can still be used in exactly the way that `dynamic_cast<>` is used though it does allow it to be used with more classes.

[`dyn_cast<>` template documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#isa)

LLVM is a reputable C++ project so this seems to fly in the face of the common saying that too many dynamic casts is a sign of bad design, also known as a code smell. Surely a better performing dynamic cast does nothing to improve its use in design than a standard `dynamic_cast`. So who is right here? Are there cases where large-scale use of dynamic casting is a good design choice in C++ code? Google turns up 690 occurrences of this kind of dynamic casting in the LLVM trunk source code.

[Uses of `dyn_cast<>` in LLVM trunk](http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q=dyn_cast+package%3Allvm-project%2Fllvm%2Ftrunk&sbtn=Search)

Comment: I think it simply shows that "sometimes, in a large software project, you have to bend some of the rules". Or perhaps "compilers, or compiler-related frameworks, have to screw around with low-level trickery that is usually a bad idea". That doesn't mean we can conclude anything about the use of `dynamic_cast` *in general*

Comment: This seems to be outright ignoring 'the rules'. I wouldn't call 690 occurrences bending the rules. I don't see anything special about compilers or compiler-related frameworks that mean they are allowed to break design beliefs. The dynamic casting here has no effect on the output code or input code of the compiler, it's simply part of the design. I could continue your argument to say that any sufficiently large or complex piece of software is allowed to flout design rules, which seriously questions this kind of design advice to avoid `dynamic_cast`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While performance hits are a reason to avoid `dynamic_cast<>` for large class hierarchies, it's not the only reason you might want to avoid them. Better performing or not, one should not be more encouraged to use `dyn_cast<>` because of this claim.

On the other hand, there's absolutely nothing wrong with using `dynamic_cast<>` when it's the best tool for the job. If its use is justified, and the cleanest way to solve a problem, then it's always right, regardless of the "common saying".

I would certainly not steer clear of popular projects simply because they use `dynamic_cast<>`s, `goto`s or any other idiom that's fallen out of favour.

Comment: Absolutely, I think it's a great project so does that mean we should take less serious notice of advice to steer clear of `dynamic_cast<>`?

Comment: no, you should keep the advice in mind when you're using them and think, "is this the best way to do this?"

Answer (score 1):

I think dynamics casts are bad not because they are slow, but because they imply that your code is too tightly coupled.

Comment: They are very slow too, though. About 1 microsec a pop for us.

Comment: @Crashworks - How deep is the inheritance hierarchy?  I believe GCC's implementation of `dynamic_cast` is O(n) in the depth, which can be very bad for some systems.

Comment: I think it's about 6-8 levels in the case I tested. There's literally thousands of classes throughout the entire app.

Comment: I agree so are you implying that LLVM is too tightly coupled and thus not a good design?

Answer (score -1):

I've only taken a very quick look at the implementation of dyn_cast and isa in the LLVM documentation.

The exmaple in the code has the following:

```
struct bar {
  bar() {}
private:
  bar(const bar &);

};
struct foo {
  void ext() const;
  /*  static bool classof(const bar *X) {
    cerr << "Classof: " << X << "\n";
    return true;
    }*/
};

template <> inline bool isa_impl<foo,bar>(const bar &Val) {
  errs() << "Classof: " << &Val << "\n";
  return true;
}
```

The test is called with a `B` and has:

```
if (!isa<foo>(B1)) return;
if (!isa<foo>(B2)) return;
```

If I understand what's going on correctly, the `isa` template (which is used by `dyn_cast`) uses the explicit specialization of `isa_impl` to link bar with foo.  In the examples given it seems that `isa<foo>(B1)` returns true!

Anyway, this is very different behaviour to that of dynamic_cast, so I really don't think you can compare them against each other.

Obviously, I may be mis-understanding what LLVM is doing, so please let me know if I've not understood the code!

Comment: Directly from the documentation:

The dyn_cast<> operator is a "checking cast" operation. It checks to see if the operand is of the specified type, and if so, returns a pointer to it (this operator does not work with references). If the operand is not of the correct type, a null pointer is returned. Thus, this works very much like the dynamic_cast<> operator in C++, and should be used in the same circumstances.

So I don't see why you can't compare dynamic_cast against dyn_cast. In your example I don't see where B1 and B2 come from.

Comment: The above code comes from a link off the page referred to in the question.  This is their (ie. LLVM's) code.  Here's the direct link:  http://llvm.org/doxygen/Casting_8h-source.html.  B1 and B2 come from an example on that page lower down.  I have just cut and pasted the code from their header.  BTW, nothing that you've pasted here actually says how the dynamic cast takes place.  It just says its a "checking cast" similar to dynamic_cast.

Comment: I don't think the implementation really affects the question I'm asking here. The key quote from the documentation verbatim is this 'Thus, this works very much like the dynamic_cast<> operator in C++, and should be used in the same circumstances.'

Comment: The implementation is pretty important to your question.  Your question specifically asks if its OK to use the LLVM version of dynamic_cast because it doesn't have the overhead of dynamic_Cast.  My answer is that from my reading of the code what LLVM provides has slightly different functionality to dynamic_cast.  I don't know the library enough to be able to tell you exactly what the differences are - but you would need to make yourself aware of those differences before you do a replace-all!